# Magento template does not load

Tags: magento, templates

all of a sudden some of the magento template like 1column failing to load.
Did anyone face this?

2014-04-02T15:12:33+00:00 DEBUG (7): Failed to load template:/home/wor/public_html/app/design/frontend/mytemplate/default/template/page/1column.phtml

Template path is correct and casing is also correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `Failed to load template` is **not** a part of stock Magento.  Magento's can't load a template error is

```
Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
```

Also — notice that when Magento can't load a template, it uses the `Zend_Log::CRIT` error level, and not the `DEBUG (7)` level.

Both these signs point to some custom code (either an extension, local code pool override, core hack, or template customization) in your system that's making the template not load.  Search your codebase for the `Failed to load template` string used with `Mage::log`.  Once you find it, the context of the surrounding code should help you understand why Magento can't load your template.

Comment: Hello Alan! thanks for responding. I have found the erroneous code. The magento collection 'sales/order_item' was joined to some other tables and in the process collection was getting duplicate items and throwing an error in the exception file.  Once I resolved this the template error was gone. Your above observation is correct and even I was confused why only some of the pages throw a template not found error when all the template are in same place and using 1column.phtml at various places.